# Inspect many sqlite databases with python dataset module

Tags: python, python-dataset

Recently I used the python module [dataset](http://dataset.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) to manipulate and store information. As result, I have a collection of sqlite databases, let say file1.db, file2.db and so on. Moreover, each of the databases contains the same table.

With dataset I can easily connect and inspect the databases with the code:

```
>>> db1 = dataset.connect('sqlite:////path/file1.db')
>>> table1 = db1[u'tweet']
```

Assuming I want to keep databases separated in many files, what is the preferable way to inspect all the databases with dataset?

I am looking at something better to this:

```
>>> db1 = dataset.connect('sqlite:////path/file1.db')
>>> db2 = dataset.connect('sqlite:////path/file2.db')
>>> tables = [db1[u'tweet'],db2[u'tweet']]
>>> for table in tables:
        for tweet in table:
            print(tweet['text'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a clean solution to this, but it might be interesting to use an in-memory SQLite database for this scenario:

```
mem_db = dataset.connect('sqlite:///')
databases = ['sqlite:////path/file1.db']

for uri in databases:
    db1 = dataset.connect(uri)
    for row in db1['table']:
        mem_db.insert(row)
```

There's also an insert_many call, I believe, which may be faster for bulk transfer.